# can this be done using a map or lambda function

Tags: python

Can the code below be done with a one-liner structure

```py
five_fifteen = []

for x in range(5,15):
    five_fifteen.append(x)
    print (five_fifteen)
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want a list of that range, you can just do `list(range(5,15))`

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating a new list:

```
five_fifteen = list(range(5, 15))
```

If you want to extend an existing list:

```
five_fifteen.extend(range(5, 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, but I don't really see a point

```
five_fifteen = list(map(lambda i: i, range(5, 16)))
```

The easiest ways should be using **list()** itself, or list comprehension

```
five_fifteen = list(range(5, 16))
five_fifteen = [i for i in range(5, 16)]
```